# How to save string and float together in the same np.savetxt?

Tags: python, arrays, database, numpy

I have a list, in python, which is given by:

`inputs = ["eos", 5, 60, 2000, 3]`

where only `eos` is a string, the rest are numbers (int). I tried to save this list as follows:

`np.savetxt(path + '/inputs.txt', inputs, delimiter=" ", header = 'Eos Pressure Radius Nt Sigma')`

but it gave an error:

`TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U32') and format specifier ('%.18e')`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `numpy.savetxt` is for saving NumPy arrays. This is a list. `numpy.savetxt` isn't the tool for that.

Comment: `inputs` will be turned into an array - with string dtype.  So you have to use a `%s` `fmt` - don't forget to READ the docs.

Comment: You can mix strings and numbers in an array with object dtype, or a compound dtype (structured array), but those are more advanced.  But since you are starting with a list, I agree that you should use python's own list writing csv module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that numpy arrays have a single data type. You mix strings and numbers, and thus the error. In addition, You should make this a 2D array so that you are writing a single row with multiple columns. To get it to work you could

```
import numpy as np

inputs = ["one", 2.0, 3]
np.savetxt("test.txt", [[str(i) for i in inputs]], 
    fmt="%s",  delimiter=" ", header="foo bar baz")

# show result
print(open("test.txt").read())
```

Output

```
# foo bar baz
one 2.0 3
```

This is not the best use case for numpy. You could use the `csv` module instead.

```
import csv

inputs = ["one", 2.0, 3]
with open("test.txt", "w") as fileobj:
    # adding the numpy "# " prequel, but you may not want that
    fileobj.write("# foo bar baz\n")
    csv.writer(fileobj, delimiter=" ").writerow(inputs)
    
# show result
print(open("test.txt").read())
```

Comment: In this way it's not possible to call a file with np.loadtxt? I used the command ```np.loadtxt(path + str("\\") + str("inputs.txt"))``` and it gave the error ```could not convert string to float: 'eos' ```

Comment: @Ramos - `loadtxt` assumes dtype `float`, a comma delimiter, and no header. You could do `np.loadtxt("thefilename", dtype="str", delimiter=" ",skiprows=1)`. (that may need some tweaking). You mix types and `pandas` is good at that. You could use it instead of numpy. pandas wraps numpy and you could either manipulate the data in pandas or take the subset that really is float and make that numpy after load.