# How to save and open string and float together in the same np.savetxt?

Tags: python, database, list, numpy

I have a list, in python, which is given by:

`inputs = ['eos', 5, 10, 20, 30]`

The first element is a string and the others are int. I want to save this in a file and then open it in another python notebook, in a way that i can call `input[0]` and get as output the string "eos" and call the others elements, for exemple, as `input[1]`and get as output the int 5.

I tried to save the list `inputs` as follows:

```
np.savetxt(path + '/inputs.txt', inputs, delimiter=" ", header = 'Eos N1 N2 N3 N4')
```

but it gave an error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U32') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

How can i fiz this error? It's important that i be able to call any element of the file (of the list `inputs`) through the form `inputs[i]` and that the elements remain string ("eos") or integers (5, 10, 20, 30).

Comment: Repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74408736/how-to-save-string-and-float-together-in-the-same-np-savetxt

Answer (score 0):

I'd use pickle in this case.. It's super easy

```
# data can be anything... 
data0 = ['eos', 5, 10, 20, 30]
# write data into file 
with open('datafile.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(mylist, f)
# read back and check
f = open ("datafile.txt", "rb")
data1 = pickle.load(f)
# [bonus] check data is same
try:
    assert data0==data1
except:
    print("data isn't preserved")
else:
    print("data is preserved")
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! is it possible to write a title on the saved file with pickles? It would be important for me to open the file and at least know the order of the elements that were saved

Comment: what did you mean by title? you can name the file anything:
f = open ("datafile.txt", "rb")